# Performance issue with lots of knockout nested writeable computeds

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a knockout application where I have a hierarchy of Writeable Computed Observables like below:

```
function InvoiceVM() {
   self.isSelected = ko.observable()
   self.selectedAmount = ko.computed(function() {
       if (self.isSelected())
            return self.usdBalance;
        else
            return 0;
   }
}
function CompanyVM() {
     self.invoices = ko.observableArray()
     self.totalSelectedAmount = ko.computed(function () {
        var total = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < self.invoices().length; i++) {
            total += self.invoices()[i].selectedAmount();
        }
        return total;
    });

     self.isSelected = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            var isSelected = true;
            for (var i = 0; i < self.invoices().length; i++) {
                if (!self.invoices()[i].isSelected())
                    isSelected = false;
            }
            return isSelected;
        },
        write: function (value) {
            for (var i = 0; i < self.invoices().length; i++)
                self.invoices()[i].isSelected(value);
        },
        deferEvaluation: true,
        owner: self
    })
}
function ParentVM() {
    self.companies = ko.observableArray()
    self.isSelected = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            var isSelected = true;
            for (var i = 0; i < self.funds().length; i++) {
                if (!self.companies()[i].isSelected()) {
                    isSelected = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return isSelected;
        },
        write: function (value) {
            for (var i = 0; i < self.companies().length; i++) {
                var currentCompany = self.companies()[i];
                for (var j = 0; j < currentCompany.invoices().length; j++)
                    currentCompany.invoices()[j].isSelected(value);
            }

        },

        deferEvaluation: true
    });
}
```

The problem is that when the parentVM is selected (via a checkbox) it takes 30-40 seconds to render all the checkboxes and update the total amounts. There are about 4500 Invoices and about 274 companies (but only the companies are being shown, the invoices are hidden using display:none). I have tried rate limiting the observables, using the deferred updates plugin, both  with and without the deferEvaluation option, manually selecting the checkboxes via jQuery (which didn't work with the 2 way binding). Does anyone have suggestions on speeding this process up? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Consider switching the templating engine.

Comment: Also, you can modify the underlying array and batch changes, then notify it of the change manually if that helps.

Comment: What templating engine do you recommend?

Comment: It's a matter of personal taste, at first, I'd use something extremely basic (that just dumps the string) altogether and just see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed a few things:

- in your writes to `isSelected`, since you are updating values that are dependencies of the `read` function, you are triggering the computed over and over while updating each `isSelected`.  you can use the throttle (or `rateLimit` in 3.1) extender to ensure that the read function doesn't keep getting called.
- in your `read` functions, you can really quit as soon as you find a false value. you would not need to loop through all of the values in that case.
- the `totalSelectedAmount` is also getting re-computed when each `isSelected` gets updated. This would be a good one to `throttle` / `rateLimit`  as well.

With all that said, it is still a lot of data to update synchronously. Might be worthwhile updating `isSelected` for each company (or a chunk of companies) in a `setTimeout` to ensure that the browser is not frozen during the entire processing.

Here is a sample that includes many of these changes: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/k4vJ8/ . I might look at updating a chunk of companies on each setTimeout rather than one at a time.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Doing the updates in batches worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

One way to speed things up is to run operations on the underlying array of a `ko.observableArray`. For example, you can change this

```
 for (var i = 0; i < self.invoices().length; i++)
       self.invoices()[i].isSelected(value);
```

to this

```
 var underlying = self.invoices();
 for (var i = 0; i < underlying.length; i++)
       underlying[i].isSelected(value);

 self.invoices.valueHasMutated();
```

If your `ko.observableArray` contains lots of elements (which yours does), then doing this will definitely net you significant speed improvements. There are multiple places in the code you posted where you could implement this. See [Knockout.js Performance Gotcha #2 - Manipulating observableArrays](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/04/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `self.companies()`, `self.companies()`.. etc outside of `for`

`observableArray()` it's a function, when you call `observableArray()` you get a real object, you can call it once.

Take a look on

- [Knockout.js Performance Gotcha #1](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/03/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha-1ifwith.html)
- [Knockout.js Performance Gotcha #2](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/04/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha.html)
- [Knockout.js Performance Gotcha #3](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/06/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha-3-all-bindings.html)